# How do I retrieve only the first n records using query in MS access

Tags: sql, ms-access, rownum

I am looking for something like rownum

Answer (score 1):

You can use TOP, for example:

```
SELECT Top 10 col FROM Table ORDER BY col2
```

Note that this will return more than 10 records if col2 has duplicates.

Comment: This only works if N = 10 :) If N is a parameter, another construct will be required.

Comment: It is true that TOP N cannot be parameterized. In the event you need a variable N, you have to write your SQL on the fly in code.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Top n Col From Table
```